# Are there Bollywood movies (esp. Sci-Fi) without singing and dancing?

Tags: indian-cinema

Are there any Bollywood movies that do not have sing and dance sequences?

I am not looking for a list of all such movies. If this question is considered too broad, a simple yes or no answer with a brief explanation as to why (e.g. Indian movie-making traditions, culture, etc) would be sufficient.

I would especially love to hear about any science fiction movies (without song and dance), if such have been made in Bollywood.

Comment: Hate to disappoint you, but sci-fi is NOT bollywood's forte. A popular sci-fi flick comes along once in like 5 years and is usually a rip-off of a foreign film, mostly American.
However, there ARE a lot of good movies without song and dance routines. Serious filmmakers are gearing more and more towards movies without songs. Or at least, without any lip-sync songs. There is, however, pressure on them from the studios to include songs.
If you're looking for a recommendation, I suggest [Ugly](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2882328/)

Comment: I have now edited the question so it should not be particularly broad.

Comment: Related question as to the why: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/2458/49.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are certainly Indian films that don't have singing and dance sequences... whether you'd still call them *Bollywood* at that point is up for debate... also remember that Bollywood strictly relates to Hindi films, generally from the Mumbai area and there are many other films made across India that are not technically Bollywood.

Here are a couple of lists of Indian films with no singing or dance scenes:

[An IMDb List](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls000736499/)

[Top 10 Indian Films without Song and Dance](http://www.top10films.co.uk/archives/12900)

I don't believe that any of these are particularly Sci-Fi themed but I just scanned them briefly.

I've only seen a few of the Sci-Fi films... there's not a ton of them in the first place. And then, there are clearly people who think Bollywood Sci Fi [shouldn't be a thing](http://www.scoopwhoop.com/humor/bollywood-sci-fi-fail/)... which I had to throw in here because I thought it was funny.

Comment: I also miss captain vyom even though its also ripoff of star trek.