# Indian Movies have song where Actors Dance but hollywood movies don't

Tags: analysis, cinema-history, american-cinema, indian-cinema

I have Been watching hollywood movies since 2005 but never saw a film where actor dance in beautiful garden and make love.whereas in Indian cinema most film earn from there music.Why there is no concept of music in between scenes in Hollywood. Does this has something to decrease movie length and in indian cinema Mostly Movies always have a title track.

Comment: Related [Why do Bollywood movies have song and dance sequences?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2458/why-do-bollywood-movies-have-song-and-dance-sequences)

Comment: Why not hollywood movies have dance tracks and love making scene in songs. Why this culture is only followed in india.

Comment: Hollywood films are musical too

Comment: but there are differences in hollywood and bollywood songs. Take example of furious series so many music tracks being played in between but none of them are like indian songs. Just play one line and rest release an album. is this a Cost cutting technique for hollywood or is this against rules ?

Comment: Statement from Related question : "For some reason musicals are a popular format and make money over there. This was the case in North America in the 40's and 50's" what this means ?

Comment: I can delete this question if this not the right place to ask ?

Comment: I think we should follow Hollywood in terms of songs in a movie. There is no need for songs to be in a movie. However, music should be there as in background score like in interstellar or inception.

Comment: Why there is no concept in Bollywood movies when they crush someone head with a press? 

Also, you missed the LaLaLand since the 2005?

Comment: And the answer to your why? is the audience, the market, the industry, we want songs preferably item songs or Unrequited Love songs so that we as an audience can connect ourselves with. This could be another reason why there are fewer bands in India as compared to other countries who are performing on an international level. In India, movies songs become famous as compared to Indian band's Original composition while in Hollywood, bands have higher chances of getting famous since there are comparable fewer songs in movies.

Comment: @AmanVerma Do you have bands in india? like westlife, linkin park etc?

Comment: Yes, but they are fewer as compared to other countries. In India, songs are mostly in movies. We have metal bands also like Demonic Resurrection which is a death metal band(Opens for bands in UK), bhayanak maut which is also a death metal band, Indian Ocean. My point was that music as a band is not widely known in India except some major cities. Recently Band culture has been encouraged by the people and we will see new bands emerging in near future.

Comment: @AmanVerma almost all of the songs I've heard are from movies and from single artist. I like Shreya Ghoshal very much. But I've never listened to any bands from india

Comment: Ever heard of Sanam band, even though they mostly cover songs but there are original compositions too. Check it out. As i said earlier these are not internationally acclaimed bands.

Comment: Yeah, actually I did. not sure it's same one. but the song I've listened is by one guy called sanam

Answer (score 1):

Both Hollywood and Bollywood have music/songs in them. You can clearly see songs in bollywood movies and you can check on end credits on hollywood movie about tracks they've used in it.

Why Bollywood movies often has dancing sequences and Hollywood movies rarely have them (almost never), is mainly because of cultural and geographical and historical reasons for both. In Bollywood, songs play important scenario in popularity of movie and income. Almost every movie has a in-movie song (clear segment dedicated for the song and song played almost full length). It's from long ago (since the beginning of bollywood movies) and it's like a tradition now. Viewers always expect musical performance in movie and songs play a important part in the movie. It can set or change mode of the movie, can be used to illustrate some emotions better culturally accepted way (love, friendship etc..) by using combination of music, rhythmical words and moving picture.

Sometimes songs in a movie become so popular it'd earn extra income. in Bollywood, viewers always looking for movie songs, in early trailers we can see they promote the movie with titular song(s). Being traditional item in bollywood movies, songs plays a important role. I can also add something about bollywood cinema, as a my opinion. Most of the movies in bollywood are based on love stories somehow. From the beginning bollywood used songs to illustrate love and affection for one another in main characters in the movie.

Using songs are traditional in bollywood cinema.

Almost everybody is using in their productions. Being a common item, viewers expect songs in a movie. So usually producers want to get better viewer attraction and bow down to common practice.

Songs being somewhat common in a movie, it gets part of movie's attention.Sometimes songs get more popular than the movie. Or sometimes songs will be popular but movie will be a failure. It'll be a somewhat good way to earn income from songs, rather than being a complete flop.

Turning to Hollywood, It doesn't get affected from cultural effects I mentioned above. Hollywood has more categories than Hollywood. and also in Hollywood they try to go for different story always possible. I'm not saying Bollywood always go for same story, but in Hollywood, movies has a wide range of varieties. category-wise, genre-wise and story-wise. Nevertheless Holywood uses music and songs in movies. But main difference is most of the movies doesn't include separate segment for the song/musical section like in Bollywood.

Being said that, Hollywood has some musical movies, sometimes actors sing and dance too. There are lot of them and you could find them in imdb on categories musical. Anyways I should mention the movie Sweeney Todd, starring Johnny Depp

Comment: Its all about tradition right?

Comment: Mostly, yes. viewers expect it. it' has somewhat geographical reasoning too. Not only bollywood follows this tradition, other language films from india have the same pattern.